# VGA/Skeletal Viewer in Windows Form?

Tags: c#, kinect

I'm developing a C# application with the Kinect, and I'd like to relay back to the user their reflection (with the RGB camera) or the skeletal view while they're using the application. Is that possible? Or is there a better way to show the user what the camera sees while running?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Kinect for Windows Developer Toolkit](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/kinectforwindows/develop/developer-downloads.aspx) has examples that do exactly this.  There are multiple examples Demonstrating how to display the depth and color streams, as well as how to show the skeleton by it'll or overlayed on the video stream.

The "Kinect Explorer" example is the more advanced of those examples, showing how to put it all together.

Comment: Thanks so much, Evil Closet Monkey!